# what is the best GUI editor in ubuntu-9.10 linux system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10

what is the preferred GUI editor for PHP on linux systems, can we use Notepad++

Comment: by GUI editor, do you mean a php IDE? or literally something that makes user interfaces in php?

Answer (score 2):

There really is no "preferred" GUI editor.

If you want something similar to Notepad++, look ate Kate for KDE or Geany for GNOME.

If you want a full IDE, try Eclipse.

Comment: From the Geany [About page](http://www.geany.org/Main/About): "Another goal was to be as independent as possible from a special Desktop Environment like KDE or GNOME - Geany only requires the GTK2 runtime libraries."

Comment: @Dennis: That is correct, but people generally prefer to use Qt apps on KDE (that possibly use KDE libraries too) and Gtk+ apps on GNOME (that possibly use GNOME libraries too). Kate and Geany are similar in features, so I think it makes the most sense to choose based on desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/) or NetBeans (http://netbeans.org/). Both of them are not free. If you are looking for a free alternative, try Bluefish (http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) or Quanta (http://quanta.kdewebdev.org/).

Comment: Uh, both Eclipse and NetBeans are open source IDE's.

Comment: Big deal. He can try them as well then.

Comment: Eclipse and NetBeans are free (and open source).

Comment: Yup, both free, if you had to pay for them, you sure got ripped off.

Comment: I up-voted to balance to zero. The suggestions are valid even if the poster's details were slightly skewed. Eclipse and NetBeans are fully open source, free tools and are two of the most highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is significantly lighter than Eclipse, IMHO. And also my choice for everyday work.

If you are looking for some casual code editing `gedit` and `gvim` has both syntax highlighting and other useful features. `kate` is fine, too.

If that matters `gedit` is a GTK application and `kate` is a QT one, but this doesn't mean you have to have Gnome or KDE in order of these to work. You need only the appropriate libraries.